# Open a row in listview automatically (android project)

Tags: android, listview, android-custom-view

For example; I have long listview and it has 30 lines(items). I want to show this listview but after open the screen, it will show 15. lines. That is, the middle of the listview will be shown automatically. Is it possible? (NOTE: I don't want to show 15. line as first row.)

UPDATE:

i don't want to delete rows. I have listview and it works well. I want to show the middle of list. Scrool will flow until 15. row and i will see all of them but it will show 12. or 15. row when listview opens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is lv.setSelection(15);

Answer (score 0):

Bind your ListView to ArrayAdapter

> final ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
>
> String[] fruits = new String[] {
>     "Cereus peruvianus",
>     "Bacupari",
>     "Beach Plum",
>     "Black raspberry"};

// Create a List from String Array elements

> final List fruits_list = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(fruits));

// Create an ArrayAdapter from List

> final ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter
>                   (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, fruits_list);

// DataBind ListView with items from ArrayAdapter

> lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

Remove / Delete first item from List. You may remove multiple in a loop.

> fruits_list.remove(0);

// Notify adapter

> arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

### Edit:

// For scrolling to specific item in your list

> lv.smoothScrollToPosition(15); // Here 15 is the position of the item

Comment: Sorry, I could not explain fully. I guess you delete items until desired row but i don't want to delete rows. I have listview and it works well. I want to show the middle of list. Scrool will flow until 15. row and i will see all of them but it will show 12. or 15. row when listview opens.

Comment: @ozan1 I have updated my answer as per your requirement